# Source text behind Rabbinic view on Dinah, Simeon, and Shaul noted in Jewish Encyclopedia

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash

Regarding Dinah, the [*Jewish Encyclopedia* states](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/5204-dinah#1) (bolding added by me):

> —In Rabbinical Literature:
>
> Dinah is blamed for the affair with Shechem because she "went out" (Gen. xxxiv. 1), and her brothers had to drag her away from Shechem by force (Eccl. R. x. 8; Gen. R. lxxx.). When Jacob went to meet Esau, he first locked Dinah in a box, for fear that Esau would wish to marry her. Such action of his brought out the rebuke from God: "If thou hadst married off thy daughter in time she would not have been tempted to sin, and might, moreover, have exerted a beneficial influence upon her husband" (Gen. R. lxxx.). **Her brother Simeon promised to marry her; but she did not wish to leave, Shechem, fearing that after her disgrace no one would take her to wife (Gen. R. *l.c.*);** she was later married to Job however (B. B. 16b [*sic*; 15b apparently the correct reference]; Gen. R. *l.c.*). **When she died, Simeon buried her in the land of Cannan [sic]. She is therefore referred to as "the Canaanitish woman" (Gen. xlvi. 10). Shaul (*ib.*) was her son by Shechem (Gen. R. *l.c.*)**.

I'm trying to track down the exact statements from the [Genesis Rabbah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_Rabbah) **from which the bolded text above summarizes**. I believe it may be at least in part from the following portion of [this page of Hebrew text](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=1&perek=34&mefaresh=raba):

> [יא [דינה הוצאה מביתו של שכם
>
> ויקחו את דינה  ר' יודן אמר: גוררין בה ויוצאין. ‏
>
> אמר רבי הונא: הנבעלת לערל קשה לפרוש. ‏
>
> אמר רבי הונא: אמרה: ואני אנה הוליך את חרפתי?  עד שנשבע לה שמעון, שהוא
>   נוטלה, הה"ד: (שם מז) ושאול בן הכנענית, בן דינה שנבעלה לכנעני. ‏
>
> ר' יהודה ור' נחמיה ורבנן  ר' יהודה אמר: שעשה כמעשה כנענים. ‏
>
> ר' נחמיה אמר: שנבעלה מחוי, שהוא בכלל כנענים. ‏
>
> ורבנן אמרין: נטלה שמעון וקברה בארץ כנען:‏

So what I want to know:

1. Is this the correct source text of the Genesis Rabbah that the *Jewish Encyclopedia* is summarizing? If not, what is?
2. If so, is there an English translation of this section available online? (My [attempt to Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%5B%D7%99%D7%90%20%5B%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9D%0A%0A%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%97%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%94%20%0A%D7%A8'%20%D7%99%D7%95%D7%93%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%3A%0A%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F.%20%0A%0A%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%20%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%90%3A%0A%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9C%20%D7%A7%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9.%20%0A%0A%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%20%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%90%3A%0A%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%94%3A%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9A%20%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%99%3F%20%0A%D7%A2%D7%93%20%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%A2%20%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F%2C%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%94%2C%20%D7%94%D7%94%22%D7%93%3A%20(%D7%A9%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%96)%20%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA%2C%20%D7%91%D7%9F%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99.%20%0A%0A%D7%A8'%20%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%A8'%20%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%9F%20%0A%D7%A8'%20%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%3A%0A%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D.%20%0A%0A%D7%A8'%20%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%3A%0A%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%95%D7%99%2C%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%9C%20%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D.%20%0A%0A%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9F%3A%0A%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5%20%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%9F%3A) seems to be only partially successful, and the translation would appear to need some serious smoothing out. I can translate some Hebrew from the Tanach with effort and some helps, but am not literate in reading Hebrew generally to be confident in translating all the above myself)

I desire to find the exact source of these statements by the *Jewish Encyclopedia*, both in Hebrew and an English translation, so I can determine that the summary appears to accurately reflect what these particular teachings on this were by the Rabbis (I realize other teachings may exist as well).

**My particular interest is in the Rabbinic source(s) that postulate Shaul is the son of Shechem (the last statement in the JE entry above)**, in contrast to some other sources that have him as the son of a union between Simeon and Dinah.

Comment: +1 This question is clear, precise, well motivated, and shows research effort. Well done.

Comment: An easy to navigate version of Genesis Rabbah is provided by Sefaria. See a relevant citation here http://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.80.4 An English version is apparently here https://archive.org/details/RabbaGenesis but I haven't looked at it at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Thanks for the links. The English version is similar to what I have found elsewhere, namely that it only is the first part of Genesis (up through the Akedah), which is not yet to the chapter related to my question.

Comment: @ScottS, give them time...

Comment: @ScottS It seems worth mentioning that rabbinic thought is not monolithic. That is, there are other sources which can have varying perspectives and interpretations from the the Midrash Rabbah.

Comment: @mevaqesh: Yes, I am aware of that. I realize there are various stories related to this incident with Dinah and her history afterwards. I just happen to be interested in some of the information related to the Jewish Encyclopedia entry.

Comment: If that is the source, it seems that the JE took some liberties with its interpretation. It is not clear at all from that midrash that Shaul was her son by Shechem, only that she copulated with Shechem. from the midrash it is first mentioned that she was worried about marriage elsewhere, and then that Simeon offered to marry her. The JE reverses that scenario, and the way it summarizes it sounds like she turned shimon down and that Saul wasn't his son.

Comment: @BabySeal: If you could answer with an English translation of the Hebrew text I posted as what "may be at least in part" the source, I would certainly find that useful, especially if it demonstrated little relation to the JE entry.

Comment: I assume we all understand that Saul son of the Canaanite women is not the same Saul as the first king of Israel.

Comment: @LN6595 Indeed, I would hope none are confused on that!

Comment: @danny please don't change what other people said. it's lying. you can't just fix what you think are typos in quotations without denoting a change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't add the sources regarding Dina marrying Job (included in the text that you marked), here are a few (the rest of your sources are spot on):

- [Baba Batra 15b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%98%D7%95_%D7%91), similar to [Yerushalmi Sotta 25b](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r3705.htm) (translation from [here](http://halakhah.com/bababathra/bababathra_15.html#PARTb)):

  > ויש אומרים **איוב בימי יעקב היה ודינה בת יעקב נשא** כתיב הכא כדבר אחת הנבלות תדברי וכתיב התם כי נבלה עשה בישראל.‏
  >   
  >  Some say that Job lived in the time of Jacob and married Dinah the daughter of Jacob. [The proof is that] it is written here [in the book of Job], Thou speakest as one of the impious women [nebaloth] speaketh, and it is written in another place [in connection with Dinah], Because he had wrought folly [nebelah] it, Israel.
- [Bereshit Raba 80](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/tanach/raba1/80.htm):

  > ר' חנינא בשם ר' אבא הכהן בר' אליעזר פתח: למס מרעהו חסד. 
  >   מנעת חסד מן אחוך, **היא נסבת לאיוב**, שאינו לא גר ולא מהול.‏
  >   
  > R' Chanina said in the name of R' Abba the Kohen, son of R' Eliezer: "By one who withholds kindness from his friend". You withheld kindness from your brother, so she will marry Job, who is neither a *ger* nor is he circumcised.
- [Tanchuma VaYishlach 19](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tanhumabereshit/tanhumabereshit09.pdf):

  > נטל יעקב דינה ונתנה בתיבה, שלא יראה אותה עשו ויטול אותה לאשה, א"ל הקב"ה חסכתה אותה ממנו חייך לאדם ערל היא מתוקנת, הוא דכתיב למס מרעהו חסד, אילו היתה נישאת לעשו שמא היתה מגיירת אותו, **כשנטלה איוב לא גיירה אותו**? לפיכך חסכתה אותה הרי בן מאירה בא כנגדה, וירא אותה שכם בן חמור.‏
  >   
  > Jacob took Dinah and put her in a box, so that Esav wouldn't see her and take her to be his wife. Hashem said to him: You have withheld her from him, [I swear] upon your life, she will be given to an uncircumcised man. That is what was written: "By one who withholds kindness from his friend". If she had married Esav, maybe she would have converted him, for hadn't she converted Job? Therefore, you have withheld her from him, so a cursed person will come to her: "And Shechem the son of Hamor saw her".
- [Yalkut Reuveni (VaYishlach)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14097&st=&pgnum=281):

  > דינה בת יעקב נישאת לשבעה אלופים, שכם בן חמור, שמעון בן יעקב, **איוב**, נבל, דוד, טורנוסרופוס ור' עקיבא... אחר פטירת יעקב **נשאת דינה לאיוב**.‏
  >   
  > Dinah the daughter of Jacob married seven champions, Shechem son of Chamor, Shimon son of Jacob, Job, Naval, David, Quintus Tineius Rufus, and R' Akiva... after Jacob passed away, Dinah married Job.

And here are the sources mentioned in the questions with their (unofficial) translations:

> 11 [Dinah was taken out of Shechem's house]
>    
> "and they took Dinah". R' Yuden said: They dragged her out.
>    
> R' Huna said: A woman who copulated with the uncircumcised cannot easily leave him.
>    
> R' Huna said: She said: Where will I go with my disgrace? Until Shimon swore to her that he will take her (as a wife), and that is what is written: "and Saul the son of the Canaanitess" - the son of Dinah who copulated with a Canaanite.
>    
> (This is a subject of dispute between) R' Yehuda and R' Nechemia and the sages.
>    
> R' Yehuda said: That he has acted like a Canaanites.
>    
> R' Nechemia said: That she copulated with a Chivi, who are considered Canaanites.
>    
> And the sages said: Shimon took her and buried her in the land of Canaan.

**Later addition:**

Here's Rabbi Hirsch's thoughts about Shaul (requested in comments). Since the *midrash* discussed in the comments does not explicitly say who is Shaul's the biological father, R' Hirsch speculates that it might be Shechem's, but he does not state that this is his definite opinion (because as we discussed, the source can be interpreted either way, though most do think that Shaul is Shimon's biological son):

> ושאול בן הכנענית. אם "כנענית" זו היא דינה, שנישאה לשמעון (עי' בראשית רבה פ, י), הרי אפשר ששאול איננו בן שמעון, אלא הבן שיולד לדינה משכם; אם כך, הרי גם בן זה לא התנכר למשפחת יעקב. היא נקראת "כנענית", שכן בנה - מבחינה גופנית - היה בן של כנעני. נמצא אפוא שכבר אז נהג הכלל, כי בהתחבר בת יעקב עם כנעני - הולד הולך אחר האם (עי' יבמות מה ע"ב).‏
>   
> If the "Canaanite" here is Dinah, who married Shimon (see Bereshit Raba 80, 10), it is possible that Shaul isn't Shimon's son, but rather a son born to Dinah from Shechem. If so, even this son did not estrange himself from Jacob's family. She is called "Canaanite" because her son, biologically, was the son of a Canaanite (man). Therefore we can conclude that even then, when a daughter of Jacob marries a Canaanite, the newborn's identity is considered based on his/her mother (see Yevamot 45b).

Comment: Including the marrying of Job reference is fine, but that is not really where my research interest resides. It is the relation of Dinah to Simeon, and even more specifically the identifying her as the "the Canaanitish woman" in Gen 46:10 and thus Shaul being her son by Shechem (apparently adopted by Simeon to care for him in that version of the story) or by Simeon, as other traditions note.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance those passages can be translated into English? I would possibly upvote and accept this answer (assuming these are all the correct references), but if I have to wade through translating the Hebrew myself, it could be a while before I determine how "useful" and "correct" the answer is.

Comment: @ScottS No problem, I added those sources because I thought you needed everything that you marked in bold. I don't see anything that I can add then, just notice that user Baby Seal is right that the *midrash* doesn't explicitly say who's Shaul's father (however, in the last source in my answer he explicitly says that Dina's daughter Asnat came from Shechem, while Shaul came from Shimon). So is there anything else you need?

Comment: `So is there anything else you need?` Besides an English translation of the passages? Maybe one more thing, based off your comment. Where does JE get a source reading that Shaul's father was *Shechem*, not Simeon? ***That source*, whatever it is, is the most important to my research.**

Comment: @ScottS I'd be happy to translate the passages if you don't need a "sourced" translation (which ones, the ones in your answer or mine?). I can do so tomorrow. As for the JE, each and every source I found says that Shaul was born to Dina and Shimon, **not** Shechem. It seems like a mistake to me.

Comment: Obviously a "sourced" translation would be great, but I do not know the reality of that at present. Hence, I would settle for simply someone more versed in Hebrew than my limited skills to translate both my original posting and what you have posted. Regarding the other, I was looking at a rough Google translation of the _right_ side notes from [here](http://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.80.1?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) and saw some comments that may relate to Shaul being considered a Canaanite (but again, I'm unsure), which by implication would be based off his father.

Comment: And actually, that reference of Saul being Canaanite appears in v.11 of the same passage linked in the above comment, which I think is part of the passage that I quoted, the ושאול בן הכנענית.

Comment: @ScottS There's nothing on the right side that helps, Shaul is not named a Canaanite, only his mother is, and that is explained in the *midrash* because a Canaanite slept with her. But again, all sources that I could find point to Shaul being Shimon's biological son. I do some work as a Hebrew/English translator (as a freelancer), and I would be happy to translate the passages tomorrow.

Comment: Translation tomorrow would be great! Yes, I see now that the midrash also has the feminine form  הכנענית, so it is saying nothing more than what the Genesis text says in that section. I find it odd, though, that the JE would make that big of an error, if error it is, and not have any source indicating Shaul was son of Shechem to back it up. Hmmmm.

Comment: first, thank you for any/all your time in this. Second, I did find [this comment on a related post](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34328/who-was-shaul-ben-hacanaanie#comment88702_34328): "Rav S.R. Hirsh suggest Saul was the son of Dinah by Shechem, and was adopted by Shimon." That may be a clue to the source I seek on that point, but I do not know what work is being referred to or what specific source text. Might you know?

Comment: @ScottS Sounds promising, it is probably in his commentary on the Torah (which unfortunately I do not own, and neither can I find online). Hopefully someone here has access to it.

Comment: @ScottS I added the translations to my answer.

Comment: @ScottS I found the mentioned source by R' Hirsch and added it to the end of my answer.

Comment: @ScottS I just now noticed that you were still looking for an earlier source. I searched some more and found two earlier sources, but they're not as explicit. One is the Kohelet Ya'akov (around 1700) quoted [here](http://goo.gl/UyoioP) who says that Shechem inserted an "impure" seed into Dinah, which later combined with Shimon's pure seed to give birth to Shaul. R' Chayim ben Atar (around 1870) in his book Ben Yehoyada [gives a similar statement](http://goo.gl/uuhxM8). So I guess this is a combination of both opinions..

Comment: Sorry, not R' Chayin ben Atar, it was the Ben Ish Chay (R' Yosef Chayim).

Comment: Are you sure those texts are actually advocating for a "mixture" of seeds producing Shaul? That would be really bizarre. My rough Google translation of the 1st reference appears  like he is saying Dinah became pregnant at 7 years old from Shechem (no comment on child), 8 yr old w/Asenath, and 9 yr old w/Shaul from Simeon. Though perhaps you are referring to text after that, which Google does not handle well translating (it speaks of a "drop" from Simon and from Shechem, but nothing of Shaul in that section that I can tell). I'm having trouble locating the correct spot in the 2nd reference.

Comment: @ScottS I can send you the exact words later if you wish, but indeed the part of the "drops" is the relevant part (the impure drop of seed from Shechem and the pure one of Shimon's mixed and Shaul came out). Both sources say almost the same thing. When I get home I will copy the exact parts if you wish.

Comment: While historically interesting, I'm not sure how relevant it is (since it is too weird an idea to be valid). I'm really seeking sources that relate just to Shaul being Shechem's son. Though I certainly would not object if you wanted to add that as an addition to your answer if you feel it has some relevance to the JE entry of Shaul being Shechem's son.

Comment: @Cauthon Did you ever copy that by chance? I don't want to inconvenience you 5 years later but if you have it and can post it then great.