# Are there any midrashim that state Shechem and Dinah were in love or that it was consensual?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, mysticism-kabbalah, vayishlach

It is written in Bereshit that Shechem "defiled" Dinah, and all opinions I've learned agree that it was rape, but are there any that dissent? I wonder if "defiled" could also apply to consensual sex before marriage. My questions are if there are any interpretations that they were in love, or that it was consensual intercourse? If so, is it possible they even got married before her brothers found out and killed Shechem? Are there any opinions that she had a child by Shechem? Was Shechem known for having any redeeming qualities in general that could have attracted her to him, besides (if you want to look at it this way) being a prince and a warrior etc? ***

Related background info that would be helpful to know: what are all the incarnations of Dinah and Shechem before and after them? (I.e., the same question relating to Zimri and Cozbi, whether it was rape or consensual, could shed insight on this, but, it would be helpful to know all the incarnations before and after as well as those).

*** *"Attracted" only in the context of if there exist midrashim where it was consensual. I do not imply that the existence or non-existence of attraction on Dinah's part has any relevance in the case of rape.*

Comment: See mefarshim here https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/34.3#e0n6

Comment: @wfb Thank you very much for responding. I can barely read any Hebrew, really. A few words here and there, very slowly, unless ones I recognize. Is there any english translation?

Comment: @wfb It looks like I can enable english but they only have english for some of them. I have always used sefaria not altorah and did not know this feature was available. maybe it is available on sefaria too but I didn't know. None of the translations to english indicate consent or love. Which commentaries in Hebrew were you thinking of when you linked?

Comment: @wfb I tried including all the commentaries they have available. I clicked the gear icon, and enabled all. But I noticed, they don't have Ramchal, they don't have the Gra, they don't have Rashbi, they don't have the Arizal's. Is there a page like this that includes the kabbalists midrashim on verses too? For all verses not necessarily this one, although if theirs happen to be the only ones who say they got married, or had a child, or were in love, then they would be most relevant here also. But I don't know which chazal say that if any. Hard to know when their commentaries arent included!! :D

Comment: The modern Hebrew word for rape is אנס, though this word does not show up in Tanakh to mean so, the word used here in both the text of the Torah and Targum Onkelos is ענה which as you have pointed out means "to defile". This same word is brought in connection to the case of a man who rapes a virgin woman (see Deut. 22:29) however this same word is brought when speaking of adulterers (ibid. 22:24).

Comment: ShipBuilding, check your email I sent you something related to this question.

Comment: @ezra Thanks! I'll check.

Comment: The commentaries indicate that it wasn't consensual but that he tried to appease her after the fact

Comment: Can't answer for all commentaries, but the *presentation* of the Torah is, She went out, he saw her, he took her and made her suffer, then, he really really liked her, and tried to talk her around (וַיְדַבֵּ֖ר עַל־לֵ֥ב הַֽנַּעֲרָֽ) and then offered to the family to let him marry her. In other words, she may have been appeased later, but it doesn't sound consensual at all.

Comment: "defiled" in this context would not change even if it was not rape

Answer (score 1):

Hard to prove a negative, but I'm sure the answer is no. After all, the verse uses the term ענה, which literally means "caused pain."

Comment: Many traditional commentaries explain that verb to refer to certain positions for sexual intercourse which, while more painful for the woman, have surely been known to occur within consensual relationships.

Comment: I still think the Torah wouldn't use that term if it was consensual.

Answer (score 0):

Dinah had a son (Saul the son of the Canaanite). See [Rashi Genesis 46:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.46.10.1?ven=Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_commentary_by_M._Rosenbaum_and_A.M._Silbermann,_1929-1934&vhe=Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_commentary_by_M._Rosenbaum_and_A.M._Silbermann,_1929-1934&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) quoting [Midrash Rabbah 80: 11](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.80.11?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).  There is also discussion about the relationship with Shechem.

Comment: Hi YSA, welcome to Mi Yodeya! I edited your question so it links to the correct sources on Sefaria, for both Rashi and Bereishis Rabbah. Great answer though!

Comment: I think the part about Dinah having a son is a mistake? Rashi says that she refused to leave until Shimon agreed to marry her (which was allowed in those days). The follow-up English ("and regard the child she was about to bear as his own") is just wrong. She had a son afterwards, from Shimon - listed as one of the descendants of one of the twelve shevatim! The Midrash does talk about Osnas, who eventually married Yoseph, as perhaps being the *daughter* that Dinah bore from Shechem, adopted by Potiphar's wife.

Comment: @MichoelR This may be of interest. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68039/source-text-behind-rabbinic-view-on-dinah-simeon-and-shaul-noted-in-jewish-enc

And a shorter comment with one of the more esoteric opinions that still says Saul came from Shechem, partially. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68039/source-text-behind-rabbinic-view-on-dinah-simeon-and-shaul-noted-in-jewish-enc#comment193519_68047

Answer (score 0):

I saw an opinion that since he was uncircumcised, she became attached to him, & her brothers had to drag her out.

Comment: welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for contributing. When providing an answer it is important to cite sources and if possible even provide a link to them. Can you please specify where you saw or who the source is?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Note in particular the focus on sources. Great to have you learn with us!